# Mostrar los libros que el título empiezan por L mayúscula y terminan en a minúscula

Tags: mysql

Buenas en una consulta muy simple necesito mostrar todos los títulos que empiecen por L mayúscula y terminen en a minúscula.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el operador LIKE para realizar tu consulta. Este operador se utiliza en la cláusula WHERE para encontrar un patrón específico en la consulta.Puedes utilizarlo junto a comodines para encontrar tu patrón. Los dos comodines más utilizados junto con el operador LIKE son:

> % se utiliza para ignorar todos los caracteres que esten antes o despues de tu patrón.
>
> _ se utiliza  para ignorar un único carácter por cada '_' que esté antes o después del patrón

Estos son unos ejemplos además de la respuesta a tu consulta de como puedes utilizar este operador:

> Para obtener todos los títulos que empiecen por L:

```
select titulo from 'tutabla' WHERE titulo LIKE 'L%'
```

> Para obtener todos los títulos que acaben en L:

```
select titulo from 'tutabla' WHERE titulo LIKE '%L'
```

> Para obtener todos los títulos que contengan una L en la segunda posición:

```
select titulo from 'tutabla' WHERE titulo LIKE '_L%'
```

> Para obtener todos los títulos que contengan L en cualquier posición:

```
select titulo from 'tutabla' WHERE titulo LIKE '%L%'
```

> Para obtener todos los títulos que empiecen por L y tengan al menos 2 caracteres de longitud:

```
select titulo from 'tutabla' WHERE titulo LIKE 'L_%'
```

> Para obtener todos los títulos que empiecen por L y tengan al menos 3 caracteres de longitud:

```
select titulo from 'tutabla' WHERE titulo LIKE 'L__%'
```

> Para obtener todos los títulos que empiecen por L y acaben en a:

```
SELECT titulo FROM 'tutabla' WHERE titulo LIKE 'L%a'
```